# スタック・オーバーフロー 多言語版：制限なく、遅れなく、包括的なものを、あなたの母国語で

Tags: 討議, 他言語サイトでの提案

この投稿は、@NicolasChabanovsky さんが Meta Stack Exchange に投稿された "[International Stack Overflows: Unlimited, On Time, and Comprehensive in your native language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316522/international-stack-overflows-unlimited-on-time-and-comprehensive-in-your-nat)" の和訳です。

---

**本文**

> #### TL;DR
>
> これまでに、「多言語サイトの使命とは何ですか？どのような問題を解決するのですか？」といった質問がありました。答えは「本家 Stack Overflow と同じです。ただ使用言語が違うだけなのです。」となりますが、それでは多言語サイトをさらに謎めいた位置付けにしてしまったようです。私‌たちはその謎めいた霧を晴らすために、多言語サイトの使命をヘルプセンターに追加するとよいのではないかと考えました。[ja.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto) をご一読いただきぜひ感想をお聞かせください。ヘルプセンターの記事はモデレー‌ターには編集可能となっているので、多言語サイトの皆さんで翻訳いただけると幸いです。

この使命の背景にある考えをいくつか述べたいと思います。まず最初に、英語を母国語とするプログラマーと、そうでないプログラマーの違いについて考えてみましょう。この違いはどのような影響を与えるのでしょうか？

[image: Google imageより]

**英語を母国語としないプログラマーが抱える問題：少ない、遅い、不十分**

英語以外の言語でプログラミングの回答を探すと大抵の場合、phpBB のようなフォーラムや個人ブログに散在するコメント、開発者向けメーリングリストのリンクなどへ行き着きます。言語については、クオリティの高い唯一の情報源といえばそれは未だに本ではないでしょうか。まるで私たちは2007年で立ち止まってしまったようです…

その結果、さまざまな言語で利用できる情報には大きな非対称性が存在します。英語を話さない世界中のプログラマーには、利用可能な情報が*少なく*、*遅れて*伝わり、いくつかの重要なニュアンスさえもが*失われます*。

Stack Overflow（本家）は、英語を話さないプログラマーに影響を及ぼしましたか？はい、もちろんです！近年、[自動翻訳された Stack Overflow のコンテンツを持つサイトが稼働](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7104/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC)されました。人の手によって修正された高品質の自動翻訳を夢見ることはできますが、ほとんどが意味のないスパムもどきの内容です。このようなサイトがいくつもあり、それぞれには何百万ものページが生成されています。そしてそのようなものを、英語を話さないプログラマーは毎日検索結果として見なくてはならないのです…これは冗談ではありません。

このような状況は、第一言語が英語であるプログラマーとそうでない私たちとの間に大いなる不平等を引き起こしています。世界人口の大部分ではプログラミング自体が大きくグレーゾーンであり、業界に参入するためのハードルは依然として高く、プログラミングの学習は非常に困難で費用がかかります。

現在、ITは英語圏以外の人々のために設計されていません。しかし、我々は力を合わせてその傾向を変えるつもりです！

**目標：母国語でのプログラミングに関するあらゆる質問への詳細な回答。**

世界のどこかで、同じ能力とプログラミングへの情熱を持った二人が同時に学習を始めたとします。数年後、二人は同じタクシーで会議のため空港に向かいます。しかし、一人（英語圏ではない方）はタクシー運転手であるのに対し、もう一人（英語圏の方）は会議の発表者なのです。

私たちスタック・オーバーフロー多言語版サイトの使命と究極の目標とは、母国語やその他の偏見にかかわらず、誰もがプログラミングに成功する機会が公平に与えられる場所を作ることです。私たちは、世界中でより多くの自動運転車が普及し、そして"開発者"の運転手が減ることを願います。

**スタック・オーバーフローのソリューション：制限なく、遅れなく、包括的なものを。**

始まりはみな同じです。プログラマーであることに強い情熱を持っています。唯一の違いは、必要なとき、十分に網羅された資料が、母国語で存在するかどうかです。私たちは持ち合わせていません。私たちは、すべての技術のニュアンスを明確にしながら、コンテンツを何度も翻訳しレビューするために何百万時間も費やさなければなりません。効率的にするにはこの傾向を変える必要があります。その為のよいスタート地点は、すべてのプログラミングに関する問題への詳細な解答が整理されたライブラリーと、お互いを助け合えるコミュニティを作ることではないでしょうか。

**スタック・オーバーフローでは多くの言語を話します。**

スタック・オーバーフローとは私たち次第なのです。プログラミングや言語の制限に関わらず、すべては、他のプログラマーを助けオンラインでの回答を求めている世界中のプログラマー次第なのです。

コミュニティの知恵という"宝物"を誰もが利用できるようにするには、あなたの助けが必要です！多言語サイトに参加し、質問し、回答してサイトを仲間で共有してください。多言語サイトが存在する理由とその使命についてもぜひ一緒に伝えてください。あなたの推薦は多言語サイトが成長するために必要なのです。

Comment: マニフェストを含め、"Developer"は「開発者」や「プログラマ」などに翻訳してもいいのかなと思いますが、如何でしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます！「プログラマー」という翻訳に変更いたしました m_ _m。

Answer (score 2):

以下は、[マニフェスト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto)の和訳ドラフトです。改善できる箇所はこちらの回答で編集くださいませ m_ _m。
モデレータ陣がマニフェストを編集できるようになっています。

---

**スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版のマニフェスト**

**使命**

コミュニティの支えによって、すべてのプログラミングに関する問題への詳細な解答が整理された状態のライブラリを作ること。

**日本語を話すプログラマーが抱える問題：少ない、遅い、不十分**

- 日本語ではテクノロジーに関する情報が少ない
- 情報には遅れが見られる
- 入手できる情報は、正確ではない、または明確ではない傾向がある

**ソリューション：制限なく、遅れなく、包括的なものを**

- 生身の人間による、プログラミングに関する質問や回答に関する*制限のない知識*
- プログラマー仲間が、必要な時に*遅れなく*知識を得ることができる
- 作成者が同じ問題をどのように解決したのかを自分の言葉で説明し、一つの解決策に関連する*包括的なもの*を共有

**目標**

検索エンジンにキーワードを入力することで、日本語で詳細に書かれた回答へのリンクが検索結果に表示される環境を整えること。

**どうすれば実現できますか？ プログラマー同士がお互いに敬意を表しながら。**

- ユーザーはサイトのコンテンツを改善しながら、模範に従ってコミュニティをリードする。
- ユーザーは知識を仲間に教え、または無料でそれらを学ぶことができる。相互作用の結果、プログラミングの知識ベースは[コミュニティ全体と共有](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/)されます。
- ユーザーが互いに敬意を表しながら、安全に学習できる居心地の良い環境をサイト上で築く。

**あなたはスタックオーバーフローの一部であり、あなたの力が必要です。**

私たちはユーザーとコミュニティ、そしてあなたに期待をよせています！[参加](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)、[質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)をして、他の誰かの質問に[答え](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/unanswered)、サイトのコンテンツを[管理](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)してください。あなたの仲間に「スタック・オーバーフローとその使命」を共有してください！あなたの支えがなければ改善されません。

スタック・オーバーフローの仕組みについては、[サイトツアー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)をご覧ください。

Comment: 和訳ドラフトのページフッタには「マニフェストを作成した背景」としてメタ投稿へのリンク(現在は英文ページに対して)がありますが、この部分も翻訳対象および【このメタ投稿】へのリンクへと置き換わるという認識で合っていますか？「背景」に目を通した上でマニフェストを読むならいいのですが、そうでなければ補足説明を加えた方がよいのかなと思う箇所が何点かあります。

Comment: @cubick あっています。マニフェストを作成した背景 :【このメタ投稿】のリンクへと変更予定です :)