# Happy New Year 7E3!

Tags: サポート

一年の終わりを迎えるにあたって、私たちが覚えている2018年の記憶をみんなで振り返りながら、新年(2019年)の計画について考えてみましょう。

#### 過ぎゆく2018年について、あなたは何を覚えていますか？

今年一年を振り返ってみましょう。コミュニティに関連する大切な事柄を何か思い出せましたか？私にとっての個人的な嬉しい転機といえば、スタック・オーバーフロー多言語サイト、特に日本語版コミュニティで仕事をする機会を得られたことでした（みなさんからのたくさんのサポートに感謝します！）。私たちは[MSEでタグ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/international-sites)を使用することを開始し、[マニフェストを作成](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2825/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF-%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%83%95%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC-%E5%A4%9A%E8%A8%80%E8%AA%9E%E7%89%88-%E5%88%B6%E9%99%90%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F-%E9%81%85%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F-%E5%8C%85%E6%8B%AC%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AA%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%82%92-%E3%81%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AE%E6%AF%8D%E5%9B%BD%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%A7)しました。そして、多言語サイトでの[問題や気づき、そして機能提案](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2834/%E5%90%84%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A5%E3%83%8B%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%81%8C%E6%8A%B1%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C%E3%82%84%E6%B0%97%E3%81%A5%E3%81%8D-%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD%E6%8F%90%E6%A1%88%E3%82%92%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A8%E3%82%81%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%81%8B)を共有し始めました。

皆さんも同じ様にコミュニティと共有する思い出があると確信しています！ *この質問に対する回答で、あなたが2018年について個人的に覚えていることを教えてください。*

#### 今年の数字

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------
|                    | Stack Overflow     |  Stack Overflow   |
|                    | in Japanese        |  in Japanese      |
|                    | 2017               |  2018             |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Questions         |     4 877          |    5 236          |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Answers           |     4 106          |    4 547          |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  New users         |     5 552          |    4 656          |
 -------------------------------------------------------------
```

私たちが創り上げたナレッジのように、コミュニティも日々成長しています。上記の結果に見られるように、今年も私たち全員が一丸となって素晴らしい取り組みをしてきました。参加してくれた皆さん、本当にありがとうございます。

#### 2019年はやるべきことがたくさんあります！

近い将来に重要な役割を果たすことになる、いくつかの重要な方向性を強調したいと思います。

- *人が集まれば集まる程、より多くのアイデアが出てきますよね！* ここ数年間スタック・オーバーフローに参加してくれているみなさんと、そして最近新しい風を取り入れてくれている多くのユーザーのみなさんに、引き続きこれからもサイトでお会いできることを楽しみにしています。
  ユーザーインターフェイスに関する知識を共有してくれる方もいるでしょうし、ドライバーについて熱心に書いてくれる人もいると思います。コミュニティーに新しいプロセスを取り入れてくれる人もいるでしょう。スタック・オーバーフローにとって「人」は最も重要な要素です。質問や回答を投稿して知識を共有し、そして我々の[使命](/help/manifesto)を伝えてどうぞお友達をコミュニティに招待してください！みなさんの参加によってコミュニティがさらにもっと面白くなると思います。
- *スタック・オーバーフロー多言語サイト間での問題や気づき、機能提案の共有*。[Meta Stack Exchangeでスタック・オーバーフロー多言語サイトのアイデア共有を行う](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317116/274323)ことは大幅な効率向上につながります。そして、私たちの共通する問題に注目がさらに集まり、新しく興味深い解決策を得ることができるようになります。コラボレーションが各コミュニティの成長のスピードを加速させることになるでしょう。「三人寄れば文殊の知恵」ということわざがありますが、異なる文化の場合にはさらに素晴らしい知恵が出てくると思います。
- *知識ベースを一緒に構築しませんか*。すべての質問を閲覧数でソートすると、各多言語版サイトのトップ3には少なくとも1つの自己回答された質問があることがわかります（これは英語の本家 Stack Overflow にも当てはまります）。多くの場合、自己回答された質問では特定の技術的な問題に関するとても重要な情報が標準的な方法でまとめられています。そのような質問は私たちにとって非常に高い需要があります。2019年はさらに興味深い自己回答された質問がベストプラクティスとともに沢山見られることを期待しています。私は自己回答された質問がさらに注目され前向きなフィードバックを得られることを確信しています。

たった1つの答えで何千人もの人々の生活に影響を与えることができる機会を得ることが、スタック・オーバーフローに参加する主たるモチベーションであり、これからもそのことは変わらないでしょう。2019年は「プログラミングと私たちのコミュニティに関する質問への詳細な回答のライブラリを作ること」に、みなさんと一緒に焦点をあてていきたいと思っています。ライブラリを作るコラボレーションによって私たちがさらに前向きになれると確信しています。

**Happy New Year 7E3!**

[image]

あ、忘れてはいけないのが！[新年と言えば...](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2903/78)

Comment: What does mean "7E3"?

Comment: @cubick Hi! Just a hexadecimal joke. =)